# Twitter Bootstrap: How to print Thumbnails as same as screen?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I want to print Twitter Bootstrap Thumbnails as same as screen, but they expand horizontally and background color turns black. I am using Twitter Bootstrap 2.1.1(twitter-bootstrap-rails 2.1.3) and Chrome on Mac.

My problem is reproduced on this page:

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#thumbnails

Here are screenshots as example.

[image]

[image]

I would appreciate any help.

### UPDATE

Thanks to zeMicro's answer, this problem is fixed. If you are using twitter-bootstrap-rails, you can remove `responsive.css` by editing `bootstrap_and_overrides.less`.

And you can change the background color by specifying it in your css file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because of bootstrap's responsive design. The following line is important:

```
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Change it to

```
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

Then the responsive stylesheet is ignored while printing.